# Why does predict() stores too many values during fitting with a regression model?

Tags: r

I fitted a regression model as the following:

```
y <- hiedata_short$income
x1 <- hiedata_short$education
x2 <- hiedata_short$age
x3 <- hiedata_short$ghi

lm.more <- lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3,
             data = hiedata_short
)

summary(lm.more)
```

and am then predicting values using that model with fixed age and ghi for values of education ranging from 0 to 25. Therefore, I create a new data frame.

```
education.pts <- seq(from = 0, # A (starting value)
                     to = 25, # B (ending value)
                     by = 1 # C (value determining the size of the sequence steps)
)

fitted.values.data <- data.frame(age = 30, # Create predictions holding constant `age`
                                 education = education.pts,
                                 ghi = 70
)
```

Then, I predict the values using the regression model and transform the matrix towards a data frame.

```
fitted.values <- predict(object = lm.more,
                         newdata = fitted.values.data, 
                         interval = "confidence", 
                         level = 0.95
)

fitted.values <- data.frame(fitted.values) # Feed the matrix to `data.frame()`
```

Unfortunately the plotting then fails because the fitted.values$fit contains way more variables than the 26 I have in education.pts / x…

```
**Warning message: 'newdata' had 26 rows but variables found have 1932 rows**
```

I can see this also in the environment in R studio. But it is not clear to me why the predict function stores the same amount of rows as the data basis of the model has instead of just filling up the given data frame "fitted.values.data"… ?!

```
plot(x = education.pts, 
     y = fitted.values$fit,
     type = "l",
     col = "black",
     xlab = "Years of Education",
     ylab = "Predicted Family Income (1000s of USD)", 
     main = "Predicted Income Given Education\nRAND Health Insurance Experiment \n",
     sub = "Age fixed at 30; GHI fixed at 70", 
     ylim = c(0, 20) 
)
```

Comment: Fit with `formula = income ~ education + age + ghi`.

Comment: @yuskox Your model never used the variables income, education, age and ghi. It used y, x1, x2 and x3 that you stored in the global environment (and told it to use in the formula). Then, when you use `predict` it also expects x1, x2 and x3 as predictors. It does not find them in `fitted.values.data` so it uses again the x1, x2 and x3 it finds in the global environment. Therefore, in `fitted.values` you will find what you would get from `predict(lm.more)`.